# Метод .val() ничего не возвращает

Tags: jquery, javascript

Всем, привет! Уважаемое сообщество, подскажите пожалуйста, почему метод *.val()* в моем сценарии ничего не возвращает, может быть я неправильно использую этот метод.

Сценарий:

```
jQuery('#get-start').val(
    function(){

        // Форматируем полученную дату      
        function parseDate(inputTEXT) {
         var RegEXP_inputTEXT = new Date(inputTEXT.replace(/(\d+)-(\d+)/, '$2-$1'));
         var outputMonth = RegEXP_inputTEXT.getMonth();
         return outputMonth;
        }

        // Получим первый день указанного месяца
        setDate = function() {
            var d = new Date();
            var day = d.getDate() - (d.getDate()-1);
            var month = parseDate("05-2013") + 1;
            var year = d.getFullYear();

            if (day > 1 || day < 10) {
                var day = "0" + day;
            } else {
                return day;
                } 
            if (month > 1 || month < 10) {
                var month = "0" + month;
            } else {
                return month;
                }

            return  day + "-" + month + "-" + year;     
        }

        setDate();
    }
);
```

В поле #get-start ничего не попадает, хотя по идее должно было прийти значение примерно такого вида:

> 01-05-2013

Comment: > может быть я неправильно использую
> этот метод

!!!

Comment: @Palmervan, может быть вопрос непонятен? http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0_%D1%81_%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC_value

Comment: @Palmervan, в этом выражении все сказано логично, [взято из свободной библиотеки][1]
[1]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CC%E5%F2%EE%E4_(%EF%F0%EE%E3%F0%E0%EC%EC%E8%F0%EE%E2%E0%ED%E8%E5)

Comment: Прошу прощения небыло времени ответить полноценно!

---------------------

у вас в анонимной функции - функции `parseDate` и setDate а это уже ошибка! Внутри функции нужно делать вызов нужной функции и передавать в нее определенные данные для обработки а не писать ее сценарий!

Comment: @Palmervan, ооо... ну вы бы сразу пояснили, но дело все равно не в этом, спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сначала возьмите значение через

`var new_val = $('selector').val();`

потом передайте его в функцию-обработчик, и, если нужно, обратно

`$('selector').val(new_val);`.

Навскидку, без проверки, глядя только на ваш пример:

```
function blahBlah(inputTEXT){

        // Форматируем полученную дату      
        function parseDate(inputTEXT) {
         var RegEXP_inputTEXT = new Date(inputTEXT.replace(/(\d+)-(\d+)/, '$2-$1'));
         var outputMonth = RegEXP_inputTEXT.getMonth();
         return outputMonth;
        }

        // Получим первый день указанного месяца
        setDate = function() {
            var d = new Date();
            var day = d.getDate() - (d.getDate()-1);
            var month = parseDate(inputTEXT) + 1;
            var year = d.getFullYear();

            if (day > 1 || day < 10) {
                var day = "0" + day;
            } else {
                return day;
                } 
            if (month > 1 || month < 10) {
                var month = "0" + month;
            } else {
                return month;
                }

            return  day + "-" + month + "-" + year;     
        }

        setDate(inputTEXT);
    }

var my_val = jQuery('#get-start').val();
var new_val = blahBlah(my_val);
jQuery('#get-start').val(new_val);
```

Comment: @Кудрин Сергей, подскажите, пожалуйста, как связать это с моим сценарием?

Comment: @Кудрин Сергей благодарю, получилось :)